# Accessing SSO credentials from ASP.Net client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, single-sign-on

I have asp.net web application which is consuming asp.net web services.

These web service requests have to be authenticated to get any response.

Asp.net web application will be running in SSO environment.

How do I make my asp.net application get the credentials from SSO and pass those credentials to web service?

Thanks,
Naresh

Comment: What have you tried?  What implementation of SSO are you using?  It will be difficult to answer this question without more details.

Comment: Is this SSO any known SSO provider, or what?

Comment: @SteveCzetty: I don't have any idea where to start on this. I fond some SSo provides but they are from namespace 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.SingleSignon'. I am not quite sute whether we can use them or not.

Comment: If you can share the SSO environment whether you use ADFS, PingIdentity or others it will be easy to help as given by Steve. It could be WP or it could be SAML 2.0 based response from the Identity Provider based on which the claim information can be passed on to the WebService. Certainly need more information to help you?